# Aggregating and flattening a dataframe using multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Long time listener; First time caller :)

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a1','a1','a1','a2','a2','a3','a3','a3','a3'],
                   'cat1':['C','D','D','C','D','D','D','D','C'],
                   'cat2':['X','Y','X','Y','X','Y','X','Y','X'],
                   'is':[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4],
                   'fs':[.1,.2,.3,.1,.2,.1,.2,.3,.4]})
```

giving:

```
    a cat1 cat2  is   fs
0  a1    C    X   1  0.1
1  a1    D    Y   2  0.2
2  a1    D    X   3  0.3
3  a2    C    Y   1  0.1
4  a2    D    X   2  0.2
5  a3    D    Y   1  0.1
6  a3    D    X   2  0.2
7  a3    D    Y   3  0.3
8  a3    C    X   4  0.4
```

I am looking to group the dataframe in such a way that it gives the below output, where each row is first grouped by the value in column `a`, **then** the numeric columns of the dataframe are aggregated (sum, mean, etc) based on category -- `cat1` and `cat2`.

```
    a sum(is|cat1=C) sum(fs|cat1=C) sum(is|cat1=D) sum(fs|cat1=D) sum(is|cat2=X)  sum(fs|cat2=X) sum(is|cat2=Y)  sum(fs|cat2=Y)
0  a1              1            0.1             5             0.5              4             0.4              2             0.2
1  a2              1            0.1             2             0.2              2             0.2              1             0.1
2  a3              4            0.4             6             0.6              6             0.6              4             0.4
```

For example, in row 0 above, `sum(is|cat1=D)` is the sum of `is` values for `a1` when `cat1 = D`. Hope this is clear enough. Happy to further clarify.

Here's the best I'm able to do so far:

```
output = []
aggregations = ['sum']
for category in ['cat1', 'cat2']:
    num_data = df.select_dtypes('number')
    grouped = df.groupby(['a', category]).agg({'is':'sum', 'fs':'sum'})
    flattened = pd.DataFrame(grouped.to_records())
    flattened.columns = ['a', category] + ['%s(%s|%s)' % (op, column, category)
                                                         for column in list(num_data.columns) for op in aggregations]
    output.append(flattened)
```

output[0] looks something like this:

```
    a cat1  sum(is|cat1)  sum(fs|cat1)
0  a1    C             1           0.1
1  a1    D             5           0.5
2  a2    C             1           0.1
3  a2    D             2           0.2
4  a3    C             4           0.4
5  a3    D             6           0.6
```

which is obviously some ways off. I can't figure out how to further flatten it and rename the sum headers appropriately. Also, I don't know how to include `cat2`-based aggregation in the results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) before aggregating, then add `variable,value` to `groupby`, then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), sorting third level of `MultiIndex in columns` and flattening it:

```
categories = ['cat1', 'cat2']

df1 = (df.melt(id_vars=df.columns.difference(categories))
        .groupby(['a','variable','value'])
        .agg({'is':'sum', 'fs':'sum'})
        .unstack([1,2])
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=2, sort_remaining=False))

df1.columns = [f'sum({a}|{b}={c})' for a,b,c in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
    a  sum(is|cat1=C)  sum(fs|cat1=C)  sum(is|cat1=D)  sum(fs|cat1=D)  \
0  a1               1             0.1               5             0.5   
1  a2               1             0.1               2             0.2   
2  a3               4             0.4               6             0.6   

   sum(is|cat2=X)  sum(fs|cat2=X)  sum(is|cat2=Y)  sum(fs|cat2=Y)  
0               4             0.4               2             0.2  
1               2             0.2               1             0.1  
2               6             0.6               4             0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach:

Group the dataframe on `a`, and category column, calculate the `sum` as agregate, add suffix, and unstack the last level i.e. `-1`, then finally rename the columns. Do the same for both the columns, finally join the dataframes.

```py
cat1=df.groupby(['a', 'cat1']).agg(sum).add_suffix('|cat1').unstack(-1)
cat1.columns=[f"sum({x}={y})" for x,y in cat1.columns]

cat2=df.groupby(['a', 'cat2']).agg(sum).add_suffix('|cat2').unstack(-1)
cat2.columns=[f"sum({x}={y})" for x,y in cat2.columns]
pd.concat([cat1, cat2], axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
    sum(is|cat1=C)  sum(is|cat1=D)  sum(fs|cat1=C)  sum(fs|cat1=D)  \
a                                                                    
a1               1               5             0.1             0.5   
a2               1               2             0.1             0.2   
a3               4               6             0.4             0.6   
    sum(is|cat2=X)  sum(is|cat2=Y)  sum(fs|cat2=X)  sum(fs|cat2=Y)  
a                                                                   
a1               4               2             0.4             0.2  
a2               2               1             0.2             0.1  
a3               6               4             0.6             0.4
```